# JSON data parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
$scope.partsLinesTest = data[0].instock; // this is getting the JSOn data 
from my http request

for(var i=0; $scope.partsLinesTest.length > 0; i++) {
 //$scope.partsLinesTest =  $scope.partsLinesTest[0].instock;
console.log($scope.partsLinesTest.replace(/['{[\]}']/g,''))
var str = $scope.partsLinesTest;
$scope.partsLinesStock = str.replace(/['{[\]}']/g,'');
}
```

The Json data is somewhat formatted as below, my problem is with instock due to the extra regular brackets and curly braces which is why I thought using RegEX would solve problem, however I can't seem to iterate correctly through the data and post it back into the view, also I'm using Angular

```
var test = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "This is a document",
      "desc": "PO",
      "date": "2017-01-15",
      "instock": "[{'branch': 'Edmonton', 'quantity': 2}]"
  }
```

Comment: The sensible solution to this would be to fix wherever the data is coming from so it provides valid JSON.

Comment: Another working solution would be to use `eval(data[0].instock)` though I wouldn't recommend that for security reasons.

Comment: Or `JSON.parse(data[0].instock.replace(/'/g, "\""))`, but it's far better to fix the issue at source than try to fix broken JSON

Comment: I've updated an answer @Darren

Answer (score 0):

A working **temporary** solution (no, better, a *temporary **workaround***) would be to use Javascript's `eval()` function (which you should **never** do on a production system because it opens up security holes!):

```js
var test = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "This is a document",
      "desc": "PO",
      "date": "2017-01-15",
      "instock": "[{'branch': 'Edmonton', 'quantity': 2}]"
  }]
  
console.log(eval(test[0].instock))
console.log(Array.isArray(eval(test[0].instock)))
```

As @Quentin pointed out, the correct solution would be to make the server emit correctly formatted JSON (which would require replacing the single quotes `'` by escaped double quotes `\"`).

Please read about why using `eval()` is **strongly discouraged**: [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0):

If it's JSON-esque you know it will have `,` and `:` dividing keys and values. I would start by cleaning out all other characters and splitting it on those:

```
var jsonString = "[{'branch': 'Edmonton', 'quantity': 2}]"
var cleaned = jsonString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9:,]/g,'')
  //"branch:Edmonton,quantity:2"

var splitIntoKeyVal = cleaned.split(',').map(function(row){ return row.split(':')})
  //[["branch","Edmonton"],["quantity],2]]
var json = {}

splitIntoKeyVal.forEach(function(row){
  json[row[0]] = row[1]
})
```

If you think your values might have `:` or `,` in them, you might have to do some other regex trickery.

Answer (score -1):

In order to get the quantity you must parse the `data.instock` json.

```js
var data = {
     "id": 1,
     "title": "This is a document",
     "desc": "PO",
     "date": "2017-01-15",
     "instock": '[{"branch": "Edmonton", "quantity": 2}]'
};

    
var stock = JSON.parse(data.instock);

console.log(stock[0].quantity); 
//$scope.partsLinesStock = stock[0].quantity;
```

Comment: `instock` is a string, not an array of objects.

Comment: Re edit: That will error. The string does not contain JSON.

Comment: I've edited the answer again. If `instock` is a valid JSON it will be parsed. Check this out

Comment: We know it is not valid JSON, we can see it in the question. Assuming it is valid is … silly.

Comment: Check the output now :) @Quentin

Comment: What output? The output where you are demonstrating how to process input that is **different from the input in the question**?